# How to convert a leaflet bound to a list of coordinate in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I want to convert the leaflet LatLng bound to list of southwest and northwest corners represented as list of coordinates.

What I have is

```
{
  _northEast: o.LatLng {lat: 10.01479, lng: 76.36605}
  _southWest: o.LatLng {lat: 10.01103, lng: 76.36062}
}
```

And I want to get

```
((10.01103, 76.36062),(10.01479, 76.36605))
```

Comment: how about `_northEast.lat` and `_northEast.lng` to get lat and long of that

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to get that done that way. But I want to know, is there any function or method to get this done in leaflet

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#latlngbounds-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.bound holds the bounds of the rectangle drawn.

To represent the coordinates as list of coordinates,

```
console.log($scope.bound);
// { _northEast: o.LatLng {lat: 10.01479, lng: 76.36605}, _southWest: o.LatLng {lat: 10.01103, lng: 76.36062} }

southWest = $scope.bound.getSouthWest();

northEast = $scope.bound.getNorthEast();

$scope.coordinates = '((' + southWest.lat + ',' + southWest.lng + '), (' + northEast.lat + ',' + northEast.lng + '))'

console.log($scope.coordinates);
// ((10.01103, 76.36062),(10.01479, 76.36605))
```